# Two UIScrollViews, synchronous scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uikit

I heve two UIScrollViews, they are on top of each other.

```
                                        UIView
                                           |
                              --------------------------
                              |                        |
                         UIScrollView1            UIScrollView2
```

I would like it, to work in the following way. If I scroll UIScrollView2, UIScrollView1 should also scroll by the same contentOffset. It must by done synchronously, so using `scrollViewDidScroll` is not an option. Do you guys have some idea, how can it be done?

Source Code

```
    _prContentGridView = [[PRContentGridView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _prContentGridView.minimumZoomScale = 0.25;
    _prContentGridView.maximumZoomScale = 2.0;
    _prContentGridView.delegate = self;

    _prBackgroundGridView = [[PRBackgroundGridView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    [self addSubview:_prBackgroundGridView];
    [self addSubview:_prContentGridView];
```

Delegate Method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (_prContentGridView.scrollEnabled == YES) {
        CGPoint p = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x -   _prevousContentOffsetOfContentScrollView.x, scrollView.contentOffset.y - _prevousContentOffsetOfContentScrollView.y);
        [_prBackgroundGridView setContentOffset:p animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: have you actually tried using scrollViewDidScroll?

Comment: of course I had tried. The delegate method is invoked too late, and UIScrollView1 stops to late, few sec after UIScrollView2.

Comment: ??? how can it be invoked late? it should be invoked before the scrollview moves its contents to the new coordinates... if its late, something is going wrong somewhere... post your code

Comment: In what sense are they "on top of each other"? By y-poperty of origin or by both subviews but one covers the other or by one is subview to the other?

Comment: @user1212112 sounds a bit like you use scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation

Comment: @meronix I meant that UIScrollView1 ends scrolling to late, so my gues was delegate method was invoked to late.

Comment: try to set animate:no in         [_prBackgroundGridView setContentOffset:p animated:YES];

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use the UIScrollViewDelegate Protocol method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
  if (scrollView == UIScrollView1){
    UIScrollView2.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
  }else{
    UIScrollView1.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
  }
}
```

Comment: It works when contentSize of two UIScrollViews are the same, however my UIScrollViews have different contentSize. I will modify and apply your solution. Thank you.

Comment: ok, i see later that you added new code with an edit... you're welcome

Comment: It seems that using `[UIScrollview setContentOffset:animated:]` causes the second scrollview to lag behind the one being touched. If you use `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]` and set the `.contentOffset` property it is much more smooth. ([Reference answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11723874/168594))

Comment: @pawelropa can you tell me your modification code? how you mange same contain size of both scrollview

Answer (score 2):

You should try this Code, 
first Declare IBOutlet in .h File,

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *FirstScrollView;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *SecondScrollView;
```

then try this code,

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  if ([scrollView isEqual: FirstScrollView])
  {
            SecondScrollView.contentOffset =
              CGPointMake(FirstScrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
  }
  else
  {
            FirstScrollView.contentOffset = 
              CGPointMake(SecondScrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
  }
}
```