# iOS scrollView setContentOffset synchronization issue

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I initialize a UIScrollView with a subview. After a button action I want to:

- add a new Subview
- scroll to the new subview with an animation
- delete the old subview when the animation finished.

for that i do the following:

```
[mCubeView setContentOffset:tOffset animated:YES];    
[tActualSide removeFromSuperview];
```

The problem is that right after the animation begins the "tActualSide" gets removed instantly and it will be removed from the animation as well.

I would like to synchronize it that the tActualSide is only going to be removed when the animation ends.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
[mCubeView setContentOffset:tOffset];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self performSelector:@selector(remove) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];


- (void)remove
{
    [tActualSide removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Of course this works, but when Apple gives you a single command to do the same thing, why do it yourself in code? Your animation will look different that other animations in your same app, unless you do this everywhere.

Comment: @DavidH your delegate can do it when scroll slowly, but when you scroll quickly , i think it will not be use.

Comment: As @cloosen suggests, I found animating view UIView to be much more responsive than setting using `contentOffset:location animated:YES`.

Answer (score 5):

Listen for the delegate callback:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and when you get that message

```
[tActualSide removeFromSuperview];
```

To quote the Apple docs (note the "setContentOffset:animated:" reference):

```
scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:
Tells the delegate when a scrolling animation in the scroll view concludes.

- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
Parameters
scrollView
The scroll-view object that is performing the scrolling animation.
Discussion
The scroll view calls this method at the end of its implementations of the UIScrollView and setContentOffset:animated: and scrollRectToVisible:animated: methods, but only if animations are requested.

Availability
Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
Declared In
UIScrollView.h
```

Comment: that delegate is for the case when you drag the scrollview yourself

Comment: I justed added code to my app - after it loads I use a dispatch_after block to setContentOffset:animate:YES, and added that method above putting a NSLog message there, and low and behold when the animation stopped I saw the message. So it does work (at least on iOS 5).

Comment: The way how @DavidH do this is the most elegant.